# Fresh Dual Boot install fails to load desktop

Tags: boot, luna, show-desktop

I installed a OS alongside OS X on my old Macbook with rEFIt.

When I boot into Elementary it fails to load the Desktop environment and shows me the terminal.

Do you guys have any ideas to how I can fix this?

Comment: Why are you using Luna?

Comment: My computer crashed and I happened to have an old live CD.
Do you think that would fix it?

Comment: Using Freya should fix it. You should have done that before posting on this site. Also I recommend using USBs instead of  CDs

Comment: What is did it have when it crashed. What do you mean by crashed?

Comment: During boot the screen would flicker as if the desktop was trying to launch and then do some cool glitch art thing and go to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Freya did solve the problem. I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and everything worked perfectly.